# How to get last active tab in Safari using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, safari, automator

I'm pretty new to AppleScript and wanted to make a simple script for Safari.
In fact, I want to activate the last active tab after closing the current tab.
This is where I'm stuck

```
tell application "Safari"
    close current tab of front window
    set current tab #(some code to get last active tab) 
end tell
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: @CJK why not ? there's cmd+shift+T, there's restore last active session in history menu and one can click on 10th item in history menu to get the required tab too!

Comment: @ankii Nice ideas, but none of those will work.  Restroing the last session doesn't help in any way - we're after the previously viewed `tab`.  The history menu tells you what URLs were visited previously; it doesn't tell you which `tab` it was in, or when the `tab` was last viewed.  History items from the present `tab` would continue to populate the list, so you'd never have an order that's associated with a `tab`.  What's `cmd-shift+T` ?  But if you're certain it can be done, you should give it a try and if you succeed, I will be the first to upvote you.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? Some extension maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: this is not possible since the list of active previous tabs isn’t stored in a way AppleScript can know how to go back and undo a window close operation.